# When does routing take place in the pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, pipeline

When does routing take place in the ASP.NET MVC pipeline?

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

Is it in step number 2 (Perform Url Mapping)?

I intend to have a few routes that have an id

"activate/{id}"

"forgotpassword/{id}"

I would like to be able to access the id early on in the pipline in step 4 - AuthenticateRequest. So that I can pass an authentication token through the id part of the url to my custom authentication module.

So can I access the id property in my custom authentication module or do I have to manually extract it from the request url?

Thanks for your help,

Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the UrlRouting takes place at step number 9 - PostResolveRequestCache.

So it does in fact take place after AuthenticateRequest which is step number 4.

This is the [document for UrlRoutingModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule.aspx)

I looked up it's Init() method in reflector and that is where it subscribes to the PostResolveRequestCache Event.

So I guess now I have to try and write some code that elegantly extracts the token from the url manually..

Answer (score 1):

I know its not the answer you want - but from a security standpoint tokens in the uri are a bad idea. They can be read by javascript and then sent off to any other site in the world.

To answer your question though, routing is an httpmodule, so it takes place very early but  happens after your authentication. see:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx#id0070044

Comment: Well I'm not sure I agree with your frist point. For starters the token will be encrypted. Secondly I only intend to use this method of authentication for account activation and reset password pages, so that I can email the user a link which will allow them to login. Otherwise all authentication will be done using cookies. Also this is the standard way that nearly all websites use for these account administration tasks.

Comment: Also your second point is also wrong I think. Every module that subscribes to any event in the pipline has to implement the IHttpModule interface. So they are all HttpModules. FormsAuthenticationModule is an HttpModule. So it being an HttpModule doesn't necessarily mean that it comes before the AuthenticateRequest Event.

Comment: As someone that performs security audits, I have to disagree that tokens on the uri are standard. Tokens on the url are recommended against - search the net - this is a common security recommendation. Of course it depends on your implementation. Encryption means a whole lot less on some systems with the POET vulnerability when the machine key can be determined remotely.

Comment: link added for reference above. If you want to do custom authentication the existing forms auth module processing shouldn't matter as your roles would be populated prior to a user hitting your controller (assuming mvc - which your post was about) . You are going to be populating roles yourself and setting your own forms auth token I'm assuming - in which case what of the existing forms auth order matters to you?

Comment: also...  I didn't have that piece of information in your initial post that this was only for resets, etc. as opposed to session identification and other authentication. In your case, ensure that token is a one time use token.

Comment: Thanks for your responses Adam. Do you have any links to articles from which I can learn about POET vulnerabilities?

Comment: As for the existing Forms Auth I am planing on reuseing the odd bit of code here and there in my code, however many of the classes and methods that are apart of it are internal so I have to either make a copy or create my own. My Custom Auth will really be very similar to Forms Auth just with a few modifications. I was thinking about making a one time use only token for the activation and passwordreset urls. But I wasn't quite sure how I would implement that. The Forms Auth Ticket just expires after a given time and I was thinking of doing the same. How would I make it one time only?

Comment: Sure - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx   and     http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/28/asp-net-security-update-now-available.aspx    should give you the main details and a link to the patch (which is on windows update now)

Comment: You want to make your token one time - I wouldnt make this token a forms auth token as that surely could be attacked for say - one hour even if a user signs out. If you are emailing, I would include that unique id in your database and as soon as it is validated, expire it in your database so the next time someone tries to use it they get a message it is expired and they must request a new password again,etc. remember you can simply login a user - you prob don't need to duplicate any of those classes - via something easy like FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false)