# Rewriting the Url with POST data in the Application_AquireRequestState event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a code which registers the route in `Application_AcquireRequestState` event of the application. Once the routes are registered, I set a flag in the Http runtime cache so that I don't execute the route registration code again. There is a specific reason to register the route in this event `Application_AcquireRequestState`.

Once the app pool is restarted and if a valid(matching the route) request comes in, the route registration code kicks in but that request is not served by IIS/ASP.Net and it returns 404. The subsequent valid requests are all working fine.

I want to make sure even the first request is also served correctly.

Is it possible to rewrite the request so that after the route registration is done we can somehow try to replay the request if the url matches with one of the route that are registered? Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add a bit of Code, making it possible to understand how you register the routes.

Comment: The point is not how I register the route. The route registration works fine because the second request onward it works fine.

Comment: I understand, but maybe you can process the request after registration. For getting to know if that works, it's necessary to know how you do it. Not the whole code, but is it a middleware or a action filter, ... I know you mentioned a event, but where is it called?

Comment: It is in Global.asax file

Comment: Why don't you just `ctx.Response.Redirect("/sameroute")`?

Comment: Redirection occurs in `BeginRequest` and `AcquireRequestState` event fires later. So in the first request route is yet registered. Try to register your routes earlier, for example in `Application_Start()`.

Comment: `Application_Start` cannot be because of underlying framework restrictions.

Comment: As per this https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3NDJ.png and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100935/when-does-routing-take-place-in-the-pipeline and you may need to target AuthenticateRequest event?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I used PostAuthorizeRequest event to register the route and it worked fine as expected. The Url routing happens just after this event and since the routes are already registered the first request is also served as expected.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, so I assume the problem is solved? Should I put a answer?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I had solved this issue on Monday itself but never came back to SO until today to update it. You can definitely add an answer as it gives important hint to the underlying problem, I will happily give you the bounty :)

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, done. Please have a look :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per below

[image: events order]

and below

[image: events]

And the below SO thread

[When does routing take place in the pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100935/when-does-routing-take-place-in-the-pipeline)

You may need to target something between `AuthenticateRequest` or `PostAuthorizeRequest` event to do your URL registration as the routing happens after that

The Url routing happens just after `PostAuthorizeRequest` event and since the routes will already be registered, the first request will also be served fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of `pseudocode`which you can use in `Global.asax`.

```
private bool RootIsRegistered = false; //register Application level var

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,EventArgs e){
   if(!RootIsRegistered)
      RegisterRoots();
}
```

This way you can be sure that your roots are registered even at the first request.

Comment: I think you didn't get the problem statement correct. Please read the question again.